# How can I debug apex class in force.com eclipse ide?

Tags: salesforce

How can I debug apex class in force.com eclipse IDE?

Comment: don't forget to select metadaddy's repsonce as answer :)

Answer (score 9):

There is currently no facility for debugging Apex from the Force.com (Eclipse) IDE, but there is the System Log Console for post-mortem debugging of Apex code - see http://developer.force.com/releases/release/Winter11/System+Log+Console and http://blog.sforce.com/sforce/2010/05/sneak-peak-the-new-system-log-console.html - this gives you an 'after the fact' view, rather than the ability to set breakpoints and step through code, but it is very detailed, down to execution of individual lines of code, and variable values.

Answer (score 0):

Since this post, the interactive [Apex Debugger](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Release_Notes#Made_the_interactive_Apex_Debugger_generally_available) is now available (as an add-on).

You can learn more about it at the Dreamforce '15 Session: [The Apex Interactive Debugger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2TvQ3rtpV0&index=83&list=PLScnZWsj0lrQSep5OZ33UVXmlgHbX6BYt).